# Typescript: Type a function where type of first argument affects following arguments

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to make a function that has several use cases, and each has a different list of arguments it needs. In explanation of what I'm trying to do, this is the closest I have managed to achieve:

```
export enum BasicType {
  TYPE1,
  TYPE2,
  TYPE3,
}

type SubtypeArgument = {
  [BasicType.TYPE1]: string;
  [BasicType.TYPE2]: number;
  [BasicType.TYPE3]: never;
};

const foo = <K extends BasicType>(
  type: K,
  subtype: SubtypeArgument[K],
) => {
  switch (type) {
    case BasicType.TYPE1:
      // attempt to use subtype as string (behavior - TS is not able to distinguish type of subtype)
      return;
    case BasicType.TYPE2:
      // attempt to use subtype as number
      return;
    case BasicType.TYPE3:
      // expect subtype to not exist
  }
};
```

The behavior I am looking for is:

```
foo(BasicType.type1) // error
foo(BasicType.type1, "hello") // valid
foo(BasicType.type1, 4) // error

foo(BasicType.type1) // error
foo(BasicType.type2, "hello") // error
foo(BasicType.type2, 4) // valid

foo(BasicType.type3) // valid
foo(BasicType.type3, "hello") // error
foo(BasicType.type3, 4) // error
```

I was able to conditionaly eliminate the second argument using rest arguments, however this doesn't feel like the best solution and does not solve the problem of typescript being able to distinguish the type of the second argument.

This is not super important, and I know I can do something similar with overloads, but I feel like there must be a clean solution to this problem. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvkQAw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey, thank you! This is super helpful and I'm playing around with it right now. The one thing I would wish for is some way to make it clear to the text editor what's going on, as it doesn't provide accurate guidance when typing it in as to the args required. I think that is maybe as good as it can get, though, so please do post the explanation!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "accurate guidance" but [my IDE prompts me as if there are overloads (screenshot)](https://imgur.com/OsAEnKF).  I'll post an answer here when I get a chance, but if you continue to have IntelliSense issues it might be worth posting a new question about it with enough information to be a [mre].

Comment: You're right, I wasn't familiar with the prompting for overloads and missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this is to make `foo`'s input take a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) corresponding to each parameter list you intend to support:

```
declare const foo: (...args:
  [type: BasicType.TYPE1, subtype: string] |
  [type: BasicType.TYPE2, subtype: number] |
  [type: BasicType.TYPE3]
) => void;
```

This behaves as desired from the caller's side:

```
foo(BasicType.TYPE1) // error
foo(BasicType.TYPE1, "hello") // valid
foo(BasicType.TYPE1, 4) // error

foo(BasicType.TYPE2) // error
foo(BasicType.TYPE2, "hello") // error
foo(BasicType.TYPE2, 4) // valid

foo(BasicType.TYPE3) // valid
foo(BasicType.TYPE3, "hello") // error
foo(BasicType.TYPE3, 4) // error
```

and it will even appear as if the function is [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with three call signatures (although maybe this depends on the IDE?) when you start typing in `foo(`:

```
// foo(
//  ---^ 
// 1/3 foo(type: BasicType.TYPE1, subtype: string): void
// 2/3 foo(type: BasicType.TYPE2, subtype: number): void
// 3/3 foo(type: BasicType.TYPE3): void
```

Then you can implement it with an arrow function that takes parameters `type` and an optional `subtype`, and the compiler will automatically understand that these two parameters are [a destructured discriminated union](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) and allow you to narrow `subtype` by checking `type`:

```
const foo: (...args:
  [type: BasicType.TYPE1, subtype: string] |
  [type: BasicType.TYPE2, subtype: number] |
  [type: BasicType.TYPE3]
) => void = (type, subtype?) => {
  switch (type) {
    case BasicType.TYPE1:
      subtype
      // ^? (parameter) subtype: string
      return;
    case BasicType.TYPE2:
      subtype
      // ^? (parameter) subtype: number
      return;
    case BasicType.TYPE3:
      subtype // undefined
    // ^? (parameter) subtype: undefined
  }
}
```

So that's exactly what you want.

---

It might be a little tedious to write out `[type: BasicType.TYPE1, subtype: string] | [type: BasicType.TYPE2, subtype: number] | [type: BasicType.TYPE3]` manually.  If you end up having lots of options and want something a little more scalable, you can take your

```
type SubtypeArgument = {
  [BasicType.TYPE1]: string;
  [BasicType.TYPE2]: number;
  [BasicType.TYPE3]: never;
};
```

type and use it to compute the type:

```
type FooArgs = { [K in BasicType]: [
  type: K, 
  ...rest: SubtypeArgument[K] extends never ? [] : [subtype: SubtypeArgument[K]]
]}[BasicType]

// type FooArgs = [type: BasicType.TYPE1, subtype: string] | 
//   [type: BasicType.TYPE2, subtype: number] | [type: BasicType.TYPE3]
```

And then `foo` is of type

```
declare const foo: (...args: FooArgs) => void;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkhAB4wD2ATgC7HACuYSAQiFAJbwAqAnjMgSJEuATQAKAUQCMAGkJDRkgExyhSRRIDMqpAF9880JFgJkAWRANMeeUXjlgUWgDNy5AFxIAFADo-ISgBzKHdbIQBtaj4IT1YObmifDVkkKHoAIyj+TydKdmBAgF0kAB8wokjo2LZOXn4k8QkVVIysmKQGMHSISmKytQq26vi6iAbJTUKwgEokAF4APiQAN3J2ABN57zaZFszogH5ZxZsB1IB3dmp4AAtt6NnBM6R0KGQ42sTk0OehNP3+OUBgB6YFIAB6B28cEo4Ag1B6s3+Q1S1DyBSBako8PolGAAG5MS82O8agl6holD9fns2kSiKCIVCvDC4QjKEjWlUOoxupR6UhsdRcQSia9SSMvo1NNTfsjokhGfRgOsIM58hB1kTGZDoQE2Yjadzlar1cBNUD9Gp9GFGa5yF5bWCkABaN3gpBOpBSYGaJD2rwoj7ksbJXby7Ko9GBaaeVYbL1KX3+tyB7nB0bjJrhrmRzp82MrNZatSMzTJgNBsmZjSaQvxrVhAMZqWSKSzRk9ShUJuplsUxopABENwgGAw5CHHbBy0wCbUzerrekuwALNPiJRu-zew7+6HGkoN12ewu+0uB8pdiOxxOp4qwSf+We9xeD1ekOuHys542X159yzOtv1nDB5yERdJUvLRr1HcdJ2PLdTwg88oPfGDP0Q7d5BtIgjGgOBECQMRu0CWEwDAEBqE4GwwjaJAAGVcwgABBIJGAgYBaDmU4BnCQDkkKHI0XyQJCTOfi3yzJQhJ5LoenEviBOlWTzWWBSwl0Qk6IVAAxNw2OCLZcCQcIAGkkHyFg3yEoFKkjMzdj8HxsScTwmIBVj2MgLjzOKUgERVKAOggdTKCQKFwmKTxwgjdoPLaQyON8szCjSzTJLQqZS2dJkkHo-TyEM4KePs9plLbHNPOE6M+k9HKaUa0yqzQ6SqpRfMejqsrhk+aDJgMMJ7EcFw3E8Xx-CCEIkEK4rjiWBstjTfh2sOebeLUKBLmuO5logR4xRJazWu+AU4oFHUDgFIURUUs5xWOvr0KpM7mIusFIWunE8TugYHoqrRZWeOLvxNNUNRLZ5LstTTtN3ACpOSLDkKISCnqzYc4LvDdQPA1HUPRsNMO-J8DH-AGjxJpDnxQ18TsPWDbwQqnsPJxGGeJxlcb-WmEfpiYcd-eGAe0JAb3g+9O2p4X2YmNdkZ3Ih9F0IA)